# Add additional properties to JSON to create GeoJSON?

Tags: c#, json, class, visual-studio-2013, geojson

With the help of SO, I was able to create a class that gets me closer to creating a GeoJSON object:

This is the class:

```
var envelope = new
{
    type = "FeatureCollection",
    features = result.Tables[0]
};

string callback = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelope);
byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(callback);
return new System.IO.MemoryStream(resultBytes);
```

Which returns this JSON:

```
{
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "features" : [
        {
            "Name " : "Joe",
            "Status" : "Dev",
            "imageUrl" : "markers/Dev.svg",
            "lat" : 34.310100,
            "Lon" : -77.215500
        },
        {
            "Name " : "Joe",
            "Status" : "Dev",
            "imageUrl" : "markers/Dev.svg",
            "lat" : 34.310100,
            "Lon" : -77.215500
        },
        {
            "Name " : "Mary",
            "Status" : "Dev",
            "imageUrl" : "markers/Dev.svg",
            "lat" : 34.310100,
            "Lon" : -77.215500
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to add another set of properties to this JSON object, but I'm not sure how to modify the class for this purpose.

The new JSON must look like this; it's essentially GeoJSON. Before each "record" there will be another set of properties `"type" : "Feature", "properties" : {`. After each row there will also be another subset `"geometry" :`:

```
{
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
                "properties" : {
                "Name " : "Joe",
                "Status" : "Dev",
                "imageUrl" : "markers/Dev.svg",
                "lat" : 34.21092,
                "lon" : -77.59384
            },
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -77.59384, 34.21092 ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
                "properties" : {
                "Name " : "Mary",
                "Status" : "Dev",
                "imageUrl" : "markers/Dev.svg",
                "lat" : 32.49323,
                "lon" : -78.43144
            },
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -78.43144, 32.49323 ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the datatable:

```
Name       Status       imageUrl          lat       lon
Joe        Dev          markers/Dev.svg   34.21092  -77.59384
Mary       Dev          markers/Dev.svg   32.49323  -78.43144
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot easier if you implement some classes

```
public abstract class TypedClass
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Envelope : TypedClass
{
    public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
    public GeoJSONObject ToGeoJSON()
    {
        return new GeoJSONObject()
        {
            type = type,
            features = new List<GeoJSONFeature>(features.Select(x => x.ToGeoJSONFeature()))
        };
    }
}

public class Feature
{
    [JsonProperty("Name ")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double Lon { get; set; }
    public GeoJSONFeature ToGeoJSONFeature()
    {
        return new GeoJSONFeature()
        {
            type = "Feature",
            properties = this,
            geometry = new Geometry()
            {
                type = "Point",
                coordinates = new List<double>() { Lon, lat }
            }
        };
    }
}

public class GeoJSONObject : TypedClass
{
    public List<GeoJSONFeature> features { get; set; }
}

public class GeoJSONFeature : TypedClass
{
    public Feature properties { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
}

public class Geometry : TypedClass
{
    public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
Envelope envelope = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Envelope>(json);
GeoJSONObject gjo = envelope.ToGeoJSON();
string geo_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gjo);
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that you specify the `lat` and `lon` in the class. These values come from the `datatable`.

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf you mean the values of the coordinates? I can't really do anything about that with the info you provided, and without seeing the structure of your datatable

Comment: I've included the contents of the datatable.

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf ah so it's just the `lon` and `lat`, previously you had different values in your question for the coordinates, such as `64.xxx` which was nowhere else to be found. Anyway, it was a simple fix in the `Feature` class

Comment: I changed the coordinates because I didn't know they would be misinterpreted as static values.